# Round robin distribution in Clojure

Tags: algorithm, clojure, round-robin

I was wondering if anyone has any resources regarding round robin distribution in Clojure?

I have a function which splits the passed data into separate maps, like so:

```
(defn round-robin
  "Divides the dataset into distinct maps using 
round robin distribution"
  [data sets split]

  (partition split data)
 )
```

My problem is that I'm not certain how to distribute these maps into the amount of "sets" defined. I'm thinking I could create the maps before hand with something like this:

```
(defn create-map-set
  "Creates a set of (count) maps"
  [count set]
  (if(= count 0) set (recur (- count 1) (conj set 
'())))
 )
```

but as I can't reference indexes it becomes harder to merge data with the specific map.

Here's what I'm expecting:

```
Input: ((2 5) (3 2) (7 3) (1 4) (3 7) (4 2))
Output: ((2 5 1 4) (3 2 3 7) (7 3 4 2))
```

I'm essentially going 1 2 3, 1 2 3 when adding data to maps.

Comment: could you include a sample output in the format you are looking to make?

Comment: I've updated the post for clarification

Comment: quite an idiomatic thing is to partition + apply map to partitioned collection: `(apply (partial map concat) (partition-all 3 '((2 5) (3 2) (7 3) (1 4) (3 7) (4 2))))` => `((2 5 1 4) (3 2 3 7) (7 3 4 2))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will indicate how I go about such a problem. Clojure is quite conducive to this sort of experimentation. (leetwinski effectively gave this answer in his comment.)

Start off with the data.

```
'((2 5) (3 2) (7 3) (1 4) (3 7) (4 2))
```

Drop that inside a thread macro

```
(->> '((2 5) (3 2) (7 3) (1 4) (3 7) (4 2))) ===> ((2 5) (3 2) (7 3) (1 4) (3 7) (4 2))
```

Partition halfway

```
(->> '((2 5) (3 2) (7 3) (1 4) (3 7) (4 2))
     (partition 3)) ===> (((2 5) (3 2) (7 3)) ((1 4) (3 7) (4 2)))
```

At this point, we get two elements (always). If we can pass these into `map`, and then concatenate each two elements, we are done. So,

```
(->> '((2 5) (3 2) (7 3) (1 4) (3 7) (4 2))
     (partition 3)
     (apply map concat)) ===> ((2 5 1 4) (3 2 3 7) (7 3 4 2))
```

Now, remove the hard-coded stuff:

```
(defn round-robin [s]
  (let [half-len (quot (count s) 2)]
    (->> s
         (partition half-len)
         (apply map concat))))
```

Note that if the input is odd-length, function disregards the last element.

My experience is that any time you want to do some transformations on some data, it pays to just push the data into a thread-last macro (`->>`) and keep whacking at it. This problem is quite simple, but the method works for complex transformations also.

Comment: `partition` is a very dangerous weapon indeed. Try this solution on an input with 7 elements instead of 6.

Comment: @amalloy: Yes, there is an issue. I put a note about that in the answer.